# cygwin can't run process saying Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: cygwin

When I run cygwin, I sometimes run into the following error, e.g during compiling.

I only have 1 cygwin open. And I have kill all other windows program. I have 4GB memory.

```
....      1 [main] sh 7508 fork: child -1 - forked process 4868 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code -1073741819, errno 11
/bin/sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this means that you

- have some [incompatible software](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) installed on your computer, or
- some installed libraries are not updated properly, 
  so you need either update them using Cygwin setup,  or [Rebaseall](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall)
  them when no cygwin processes are running.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have insufficient installed memory to support your application, cygwin, windows, and your other programs and services running on your system.